# Django: reusable templates: extend from base.html

Tags: python, django, django-templates

What is the most reusable way for the "extends" method in django templates?

I have seen this very often:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

Unfortunately this does not work for me. The ordering of the template loader loads a template from a different app first.

I have a default django project and application created from scratch with Django1.8.

What should I do:

- use a different name like 'my_base.html'
- alter the ordering of the template loader
- other solution?

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to solve this problem is to namespace your templates.  Create an application and inside the application directory (where you have the default `views.py`) create a templates directory, and inside that directory create a subdirectory which is the name of the application.

Imagine you have a project `myproj` and an app called registration, then you would have:

```
.
├── manage.py
├── myproj
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── registration
    ├── admin.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── migrations
    │   └── __init__.py
    ├── models.py
    ├── templates
    │   └── registration
    │       └── base.html
    ├── tests.py
    └── views.py
```

Now even if you have another application with a template called `base.html`, you can always load the specific template you need with `{% extends 'registration/base.html' %}`

Comment: Yes, this works well for templates from the app called "registration". If I want the "registration" app to be reusable, which template does registration/base.html extend from?

Comment: "which template does registration/base.html extend from?" => the canon is to extend "base.html", which is supposed to be the project's own base template, and let the developpers override your app's templates if they need to (which is often the case).